# Marshaling and Unmarshaling using Castor

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, marshalling, castor

I want to Marshal and unmarshal the list of my class objects say `java.util.List<MyObject>`. I am planning to use Castor for it, I will have to use the **Castor-0.9.5.*.jar** version.

Additionally I have the XML Schema for my Marshaled object(`MyObject`). `MyObject` class does not have a default constructor, it only has a parametrized constructor which sets all fields. And there are no setter methods for any field in `MyObject` class. I can not modify `MyObject` class at all.

Here is the snippet of `MyObject` class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private final SomeEnumType type;
    private final CutomObject custObjs[];
    private final int index;
    private final String[] strs;
    private final int rows[];

    // NOTE: This class also has getter methods for all the fields.
    // NOTE: There are NO setters methods and all fields are final

    public MyObject(SomeEnumType type, CutomObject custObjs[], 
                    int index, String strs[], int rows[])
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.custObjs = custObjs;
        this.index = index;
        this.strs = strs;
        this.rows = rows;
    }

}
```

My questions are:

1. Is Castor the right choice for this scenario? If not what are better choices?
2. How to created the Castor mapping in my case. I tried using [O2XMapper](http://o2xmapper.sourceforge.net/) for this but it does not work as `MyObject` class does not have a default constructor?
3. Is there a way to use the XML Schema of `MyObject` to generate Castor mapping.
4. I could not find the `org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLContext` and `org.castor.xml.BackwardCompatibilityContext` classes in castor jar, Are they not part of Castor jar ?

Comment: Downvoter, please care to explain your down vote.

Answer (score 1):

i prefer to use jaxB as it is light weight and marshalling and unmarshalling will not occupy much memories 
[click here for example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Comment: I can not make any changes to `MyObject` class, so can not annotate it. Can JaxB still be used?

Comment: @john :- if you could share your MyObject class then will try to identify it

Comment: I have added snippet of `MyObject` class in the question. Could you please take a look.